# How to get difference between days and date

Tags: php

```
function duration($day, $date)
{
    $date1 = $date;
    //$date2 = date_create("Y/m/d");        
    //$date1 = date_create("Y/m/d", strtotime($date));
    //echo $date1;
    //echo $date2;exit;

    $date1 = date_create($date);        
    $date2 = date_create(date('Y-m-d'));
    $diff = date_diff($date1, $date2);
    return $diff->format("%a");
}
```

I want difference between days ex. I have entered `10` days and date is `17-12-2015` than I must want `27-12-2015` so how to get it?

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Comment: you want to add days or subtract days from particular days, is that the case?

Comment: I want to add days i make calculation for expire date in date is 17-12-2015 then user add 10 day then after 10 days that item have expire.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Please try this,

```
$date = date_create('2000-01-01');
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string('10 days'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');
```

this will help you to add number of days, month etc to date.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Thanks Amit it more help for me.

Comment: @HirenKukadiya Thats fine.

Comment: i have days in numeric not in string format it is numeric format any solution for numeric values

Comment: @HirenKukadiya did not get you here, can you please put an example?

Comment: $day = 10;
// It comes from database in numeric.in database store only numeric value like 5,10,20 etc... 
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$date = date_create($date1);
date_add($date, date_interval_create_from_date_string($day));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d');